# Xmonad extension to cycle recent windows

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I find it a bit awkward in xmonad to switch back and forth between two windows.  Is there an extension (or a part of core xmonad) which allows this?

For example, I want to switch between firefox and emacs often, and they might not be in the same workspace. I currently do this using gotoMenu by typing `M-g firefox<cr>` and `M-g emacs<cr>` but this is awkward, especially if there's more than one instance of either app.  Ideally I'd like a single shortcut to perform an action like give-focus-to-most-recently-used-unfocussed-window, which I could just press over and over to switch back and forth.

Comment: I don't think that this question belongs on stackoverflow, as it is not programming related.

Comment: Perhaps not, although there's plenty of other questions about how to configure xmonad (which you do by programming in Haskell)

Comment: have you seen toggleWS in XMonad.Actions.CycleWS to toggle between current and last viewed hidden workspace?

Comment: Yes but this is for workspaces, not windows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[XMonad.Actions.GroupNavigation](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Actions-GroupNavigation.html) seems to be a perfect fit.  To let the module track your window history, make sure that `logHook` invokes `historyHook`. For example:

```
import XMonad.Actions.GroupNavigation
...
main = xmonad $ defaultConfig {
   ...
   , logHook = myLogHook xmobars >> historyHook
}
```

Then create a key binding for the following expression, which will toggle between the current and most recent window.

```
("M-x", nextMatch History (return True))
```

Comment: This works perfectly - although my key binding looks like `((modm, xK_x), nextMatch History (return True))`

Comment: @Matthew If you're using `XMonad.Util.EZConfig.additionalKeysP` to add extra key bindings, you can specify them in this stringy format instead. Or (import from the same place), you can use `additionalKeys` to add them as you are doing (with (modm, xK_x)).

Comment: i had to delete `xmobars`

Comment: I don't get it. This is like Alt-Tab behavior, but severely limited, because it can't cycle most recently used applications, only application in singular